# How to run FFMPEG at my web host server

Tags: ffmpeg, sharpffmpeg

I want to perform some video process at my web host server. I don't think the web host server will allow me to execute an exe file for security reasons.

Should I use SharpFFMpeg?

I have downloaded SharpFFMpeg. But it's lacking a proper documentation.

Can someone give one example how to perform a conversion from one video format to another?

I have written my execution program, but the compiler says it cannot file the file specified. What's wrong with it?

```
        string command = @"D:\Recorded TV\ffmpeg.exe -i ""Australia's Toughest Police_QUEST_2013_04_17_21_57_00.wtv"" -s 800x400 throughCS.mp4";
        try
        {
            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("\"" + command + "\"");
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo = psi;
            proc.Start();
            string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            tb1.Text = result;
            Debug.WriteLine(result);
        }
```

Comment: You should explain which server technology you can use. Which permissions do you have and so on.

Comment: The server is using ASP .NET 3.5

Comment: My server doesn't state what permission I have got

Comment: I expect that use shared hosting?

Comment: I don't really know. I am using 123-reg. The documentation sucks. It doesn't even say some very basic things and the framework version is really old. I really regret have consumed that.

Comment: Why don't you simple write a kind of hello world programm which just tries to execute ffmpeg and see what happens.

Comment: I am studying how to execute an exe file at my computer.
it seems quite complicated

Comment: No in general it's quiet simple. There is the diagnostic process class with that one you can start processes. Right now I cannot add a full example, but it should be easy to google.

Comment: have you ever used sharpFFmpeg?
do i get more control over using the exe file?

Comment: No I never uses that lib, but I would recomment to use the least version of ffmpeg.

Comment: I use FFmpeg to convert a WTV file to an mp4 file. The mp4 file is even larger!! How could that be? I thought WTV format is one of the most uncompressed format

Comment: That depends on the parameters you are using. See also the documentation.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29009/discussion-between-user1978421-and-rekire)